# NoClassDefFoundError: org/docx4j/openpackaging/exceptions/Docx4JException when executing outside IDE

Tags: java, apache-poi, noclassdeffounderror, docx4j

I am currently building a small java application using Apache POI and docx4j which protects a word document. When building and running the Maven project in my IDE (Netbeans 8.1) is executes.

When starting the class from the command-line a `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` for `org/docx4j/openpackaging/exceptions/Docx4JException` is thrown

> $ java -jar DocxProtect-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar  Error: A JNI error has
>   occurred, please check your installation and try again Exception in
>   thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/docx4j/openpackaging/exceptions/Docx4JException   at
>   java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)    at
>   java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)    at
>   java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)    at
>   java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)   at
>   java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)    at
>   sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
>     at
>   sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.docx4j.openpackaging.exceptions.Docx4JException   at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)     at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)     ... 7 more

I do build a fat-jar using maven which includes all the dependencies. When running the project from the IDE it is using the following command;

> /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
>   -classpath /Users/petervannes/NetBeansProjects/DocxProtect/target/classes:/Users/petervannes/.m2/repository/org/apache/poi/poi/3.14/poi-3.14.jar:/Users/petervannes/.m2/repository/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.10/commons-codec-1.10.jar:/Users/petervannes/.m2/repository/org/docx4j/docx4j/3.2.2/docx4j-3.2.2.jar:/Users/petervannes/.m2/repository/org/plutext/jaxb-svg11/1.0.2/jaxb-svg11-1.0.2.jar:/Users/petervannes/.m2/repository/org/plutext/jaxb-xslfo/1.0.1/jaxb-xslfo-1.0.1.jar:/Users/petervannes/.m2/repository/org/plutext/jaxb-xmldsig-core/1.0.0/jaxb-xmldsig-core-1.0.0.jar:/Users/petervannes/.m2/repository/net/engio/mbassador/1.1.10/mbassador-1.1.10.jar:/Users/petervannes/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.5/slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar:/Users/petervannes/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jcl-over-slf4j/1.7.5/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.5.jar:/Users/petervannes/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/1.7.5/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar:/Users/petervannes/.m2/repository/log4j/log4j/1.2.17/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/Users/petervannes/.m2/repository/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.4/commons-lang-2.4.jar:/Users/petervannes/.m2/repository/commons-io/commons-io/1.3.1/commons-io-1.3.1.jar:/Users/petervannes/.m2/repository/org/apache/xmlgraphics/xmlgraphics-commons/1.5/xmlgraphics-commons-1.5.jar:/Users/petervannes/.m2/repository/org/apache/xmlgraphics/fop/1.1/fop-1.1.jar:/Users/petervannes/.m2/repository/org/apache/xmlgraphics/batik-svg-dom/1.7/batik-svg-dom-1.7.jar:/Users/petervannes/.m2/repository/org/apache/xmlgraphics/batik-anim/1.7/batik-anim-1.7.jar:/Users/petervannes/.m2/repository/org/apache/xmlgraphics/batik-css/1.7/batik-css-1.7.jar:/Users/petervannes/.m2/repository/org/apache/xmlgraphics/batik-dom/1.7/batik-dom-1.7.jar:/Users/petervannes/.m2/repository/org/apache/xmlgraphics/batik-parser/1.7/batik-parser-1.7.jar:/Users/petervannes/.m2/repository/org/apache/xmlgraphics/batik-util/1.7/batik-util-1.7.jar:/Users/petervannes/.m2/repository/org/apache/xmlgraphics/batik-bridge/1.7/batik-bridge-1.7.jar:/Users/petervannes/.m2/repository/org/apache/xmlgraphics/batik-script/1.7/batik-script-1.7.jar:/Users/petervannes/.m2/repository/org/apache/xmlgraphics/batik-js/1.7/batik-js-1.7.jar:/Users/petervannes/.m2/repository/org/apache/xmlgraphics/batik-xml/1.7/batik-xml-1.7.jar:/Users/petervannes/.m2/repository/org/apache/xmlgraphics/batik-awt-util/1.7/batik-awt-util-1.7.jar:/Users/petervannes/.m2/repository/org/apache/xmlgraphics/batik-gvt/1.7/batik-gvt-1.7.jar:/Users/petervannes/.m2/repository/org/apache/xmlgraphics/batik-transcoder/1.7/batik-transcoder-1.7.jar:/Users/petervannes/.m2/repository/org/apache/xmlgraphics/batik-svggen/1.7/batik-svggen-1.7.jar:/Users/petervannes/.m2/repository/org/apache/xmlgraphics/batik-extension/1.7/batik-extension-1.7.jar:/Users/petervannes/.m2/repository/org/apache/xmlgraphics/batik-ext/1.7/batik-ext-1.7.jar:/Users/petervannes/.m2/repository/org/apache/avalon/framework/avalon-framework-api/4.3.1/avalon-framework-api-4.3.1.jar:/Users/petervannes/.m2/repository/org/apache/avalon/framework/avalon-framework-impl/4.3.1/avalon-framework-impl-4.3.1.jar:/Users/petervannes/.m2/repository/xalan/xalan/2.7.1/xalan-2.7.1.jar:/Users/petervannes/.m2/repository/xalan/serializer/2.7.1/serializer-2.7.1.jar:/Users/petervannes/.m2/repository/net/arnx/wmf2svg/0.9.0/wmf2svg-0.9.0.jar:/Users/petervannes/.m2/repository/org/apache/poi/poi-scratchpad/3.8/poi-scratchpad-3.8.jar:/Users/petervannes/.m2/repository/org/antlr/antlr-runtime/3.3/antlr-runtime-3.3.jar:/Users/petervannes/.m2/repository/org/antlr/stringtemplate/3.2.1/stringtemplate-3.2.1.jar:/Users/petervannes/.m2/repository/antlr/antlr/2.7.7/antlr-2.7.7.jar:/Users/petervannes/.m2/repository/com/google/guava/guava/17.0/guava-17.0.jar
>   com.reddipped.docxprotect.DocxProtect

So instead of executing the fat jar is executes the compiled classed and uses the classes from the lib folder in the project.

I have compared all classes in the MANIFEST of the fat-jar and the classpath when executing from Netbeans. Both are the same. What is surprising me is that the NoClassDefFoundError is thrown for a class in a jar which is included.

Any ideas, hints, tips how to resolve this?
Cheers,
Peter

== Update 1 ==

The format of the classpath in the MANIFEST.MF seems to be odd. Each new line of the classtpath seems to have an indentation character which brakes the paths of the jars.

According to the [JAR File Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html#Manifest_Specification) there should spaces between jar files, not IN the file names.

> Class-Path: The value of this attribute specifies the relative URLs of
>   the extensions or libraries that this application or extension needs.
>   URLs are separated by one or more spaces. The application or extension
>   class loader uses the value of this attribute to construct its
>   internal search path.

Manifest-Version: 1.0
Built-By: petervannes
Class-Path: lib/poi-3.14.jar lib/commons-codec-1.10.jar lib/docx4j-3.2
 .2.jar lib/jaxb-svg11-1.0.2.jar lib/jaxb-xslfo-1.0.1.jar lib/jaxb-xml
 dsig-core-1.0.0.jar lib/mbassador-1.1.10.jar lib/slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar 
 lib/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.5.jar lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar lib/log4j-1.
 2.17.jar lib/commons-lang-2.4.jar lib/commons-io-1.3.1.jar lib/xmlgra
 phics-commons-1.5.jar lib/fop-1.1.jar lib/batik-svg-dom-1.7.jar lib/b
 atik-anim-1.7.jar lib/batik-css-1.7.jar lib/batik-dom-1.7.jar lib/bat
 ik-parser-1.7.jar lib/batik-util-1.7.jar lib/batik-bridge-1.7.jar lib
 /batik-script-1.7.jar lib/batik-js-1.7.jar lib/batik-xml-1.7.jar lib/
 batik-awt-util-1.7.jar lib/batik-gvt-1.7.jar lib/batik-transcoder-1.7
 .jar lib/batik-svggen-1.7.jar lib/batik-extension-1.7.jar lib/batik-e
 xt-1.7.jar lib/avalon-framework-api-4.3.1.jar lib/avalon-framework-im
 pl-4.3.1.jar lib/xalan-2.7.1.jar lib/serializer-2.7.1.jar lib/wmf2svg
 -0.9.0.jar lib/poi-scratchpad-3.8.jar lib/antlr-runtime-3.3.jar lib/s
 tringtemplate-3.2.1.jar lib/antlr-2.7.7.jar lib/guava-17.0.jar
Created-By: Apache Maven 3.0.5
Build-Jdk: 1.8.0_60

Comment: Have you tried to open the jar file using an archive manager and look for the library inside?

Comment: Yup, the package  `org/docx4j/openpackaging/exceptions/Docx4JException`  is in jar `docx4j-3.2.2.jar`. docz4j-3.2.2.jar is available in the folder lib of the fat-jar. I see some anomaly in the MANIFEST.MF though. (See update)

Answer (score 1):

Solved it, initially started with the maven-jar-plugin to build the jar. After replacing this plugin with the maven-shade-plugin 2.4.3 the jar ran without issues. Possibly 6 overlapping classes were causing the issue.